# Metodo de eliminar al inicio Lista enlazada simple

Tags: java, lista, netbeans, algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos

Cual es el código en java para el método de eliminar un nodo al inicio en una lista enlazada simple.
Pido código en java ya que programo en java y estoy usando NetBeans.

Comment: Hola Kevin, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.